# Is there a possible one line equation to find how many positive numbers directly follow another positive number in a given row made up of 50 columns?

Tags: excel, vba, count, equation, countif

I would like to create a one cell equation that I can plug into excel that determines how many times a positive number directly follows another positive number.

I have a row with 50 columns in it and each column has a different value in it. This is part of a table, so ideally a one cell solution would be perfect because then I can drag and drop it throughout the table, but I'm not sure this is possible in excel...? any ideas?

I think I'll have to use some form of offset, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Post some sample data and what you have tried yet.

Comment: Total number of pairs, or longest run of positive numbers?

Comment: @TimWilliams I want the total number of times that a positive number came after another positive number.

Comment: @TimWilliams ahhhh that's really clever.... thank you!! gave me another way of looking at this. Math is limitless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See example below, entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and dragged down:

[image]

Comment: Simple & clever +:)